# GAE script to authorize networks on CloudSQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am working on a project where i need access to Cloud SQL but my Ip address is frequently changing (10 times a day or more). Is there a way to tell Cloud SQL about my new ip address using scripting to allow access from it? At the moment i have to use the cloud console, but if i could write a script.

Comment: perhaps 'mechanize' or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing Cloud SQL from AppEngine, you don't have to authorize the IP address. You must authorize the AppEngine application as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#appengine).

EDIT:
If this is your local (ISP) ip address that keeps changing, then maybe you can setup a SSH tunnel :

- Create an instance on Compute engine, can be the cheapest
- ssh to the instance with params -L 3306:cloudsqlip:3306

Now authorize the ip address (no need of a static ip, can be the ephemeral) of the compute instance. You should be able to connect to your local machine 127.0.0.1:3306 and your traffic will be tunneled to your cloud sql instance.

Comment: I think Matt is talking about using a client locally to connect to the remote db.

Comment: yes i can do this, although i will probably do something clever using my companies offsite infrastructure (not GAE based and has static ips) instead of using a compute instance. (to clarify the question, i work from home and so have a dev instance of GAE but it needs to talk to the CloudSQL)

Comment: @Matt yes, any machine you ssh into with a static ip will do, if there is no firewall blocking your traffic to cloud sql. Advantage of a compute engine instance is the speed on the internal Google network.

Comment: it would add less than $0.01 to your hourly fee ;) https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/

Answer (score 1):

I have just found out that on the Cloud Console in Access Control, one can use a DNS name, rather than just an IP. Google is pretty awesome.

So in Access Control simply put a Domain Name as allowed access, and use a simple no-ip service like ddns.net to keep the domain name up to date with the dynamic ip.

Comment: Even though your method contradicts Google's docs, I've had someone try it out just in case. Alas, he said the Access Control simply refused to accept DNS names. What do you think?